# Deactivate tooltip in Altair

Tags: python, altair

I am looking at [this example](https://altair-viz.github.io/gallery/grouped_bar_chart_with_error_bars.html) of a bar chart with error bars in Altair with Python. If one hovers over the errorbars one gets information about properties of the data. However, I'd like to deactivate this. How can I do this? The code is this one:

```
import altair as alt
from vega_datasets import data

source = data.barley()

bars = alt.Chart().mark_bar().encode(
    x='year:O',
    y=alt.Y('mean(yield):Q', title='Mean Yield'),
    color='year:N',
)

error_bars = alt.Chart().mark_errorbar(extent='ci').encode(
    x='year:O',
    y='yield:Q'
)

alt.layer(bars, error_bars, data=source).facet(
    column='site:N'
)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can override the default tooltip using the `tooltip` encoding channel. If you want no tooltip, you can set it to `alt.value(None)`:

```
error_bars = alt.Chart().mark_errorbar(extent='ci').encode(
    x='year:O',
    y='yield:Q',
    tooltip=alt.value(None),
)
```

It's a bit unfortunate that `mark_errorbar` does not support the `tooltip=None` argument, as other mark types do; that would feel more natural I think.

Comment: This does not seem to work for mark_boxplot. I tried alt.value(None), None, False but the tooltip keeps appearing. Any hints?